# Adding additional column in All subscriber in Marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can we add a additional column in Subscriber list in marketing cloud?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add it as an additonal attribute in profile management. Not only will the all subscribers list contain this additional column, but so would other lists.

References:

- [Create profile and attribute properties](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/create_profile_and_preference_attributes/)
- [Attribute Properties](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/profile_and_preference_attributes/attribute_properties/)